# Where is java installed in ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux

I have installed java with the command:

`sudo apt install openkdk-17-jdk`

Now I installed gradle, but can't use it, I have received error:

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/bin/java

```
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

- Need to say I have set the variable on my own since the JAVA_HOME wasn't set.

I have tried all the options:

- `export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f $(which java))` (/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java)
- `export JAVA_HOME=$(which java)` (/usr/bin/java)
- `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/java`

all options from the `whereis java`:
java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

- /usr/bin/java - not a directory
- /etc/java - contains a `security` folder and it all
- /usr/share/java - doesn't contains a `java`:

```
ls /usr/share/java/java*
/usr/share/java/java-atk-wrapper.jar  /usr/share/java/java_defaults.mk  /usr/share/java/javaewah-1.1.7.jar  /usr/share/java/javaewah.jar
```

Comment: JAVA_HOME is not the bin directory. It's one above that. So do the first one `(/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` but the parent dir

Comment: Yea ... Ubuntu `apt` installs Java under "/usr/lib/jvm".  There can be multiple versions installed.  But `whereis` only searches `$PATH` and doesn't follow the symlink chain from "/usr/bin/java" (via "/etc/alternatives/java") to where the (chosen) executable is actually installed.

Comment: @Michael thanks, but nothing helps. I set the JAVA_HOME='', and works. I do not know what to do - gitlab-runner require to set the JAVA_HOME, but gradle doesn't executes when JAVA_HOME is set

Comment: I found that java actually installed in usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/ but gradle doesn't work with this option.

Comment: Have you checked if you have the folder in  "/usr/lib/jvm"? If you have, you can set it to point to that folder. Example: `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64`. You need to check if the folder `java-17-openjdk-amd64` is correct and adapt it to the correct folder.

Comment: @Raffa thanks! Without a bin folder must be set! As you said: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: "*Without a bin folder must be set!*" Yes, hence why I told you that 20 minutes earlier: "*JAVA_HOME is not the bin directory. It's one above that*" lmao

Comment: `which java` → `/usr/bin/java` and `whereis java` → `java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz` I believed until today that both commands would return the same content, but it isn't the case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/java` will point to the bin folder. This is just a symbolic link to the actual installation folder.

You should make it if you update it to `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64`.

Note you should use the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, Java is commonly installed in the `/usr/lib/jvm/` directory.

To check Java Version: `java -version`